# SharePoint Calendar Approval Notification Sending to Incorrect Approvers

Tags: 2013, workflow, sharepoint-calendar, workflow-activity, nintex

I have created a PTO calendar in SharePoint 2013 that has three separate work flows (Nintex) that activate if a condition is met. A notification should be sent to the appropriate approver on the workflow, however the notification is being sent to the approvers on all workflows. How can I stop the notification from going to all approvers and instead just go to the approver associated with the group?

More details:
Workflow 1 begins when team "A" is selected - Approver John should receive notification for request.
Workflow 2 begins when team "B" is selected - Approver Jane should receive notification for request.
Workflow 3 begins when team "C" is selected - Approver Susie should receive notification for request.
As of right now when an event is created on the calendar John, Jane and Susie are receiving the notification that approval is required.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly you cannot set which wf is started, you can trigger wf when item is modified. So you should have one wf that starts, checks who is selected and then starts that specific wf this way you can avoid starting all 3 workflows.

Comment: Thank you! I had that the workflows set to start when items are created (conditionally) and start when items are modified (no conditions). I added the same conditions to the modified and my issue was resolved